# Code segmentation fault (core dumped) pthread creation

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I am a newbie at thread programming and trying to learn how to create threads. I have created a thread and passed the arguments, but during the execution, I get a segmentation fault. There is possibly a malfunction while using the address space. The code goes as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct task_spec_struct 
{ 
    char task_type;
    int period,r_min,r_max;
}s1;

int gen_rand(int a, int b) 
{ 
    srand(time(NULL));
     int x = a+(rand()%(b-a));
      return x;
}

//task body to utilize CPU to perform computations

void* periodic_task(void* arg)
{
   struct task_spec_struct *arg_struct = (struct task_spec_struct*) arg;


  int rand_num = gen_rand(arg_struct->r_min, arg_struct->r_max);
  while(1)

   {
  int i, j=0;
  for(i=0; i<rand_num; i++)
  {
     j=j+i;
     }
  usleep((arg_struct->period)*1000);
  printf("Executing thread1");
  }
  pthread_exit(0);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int num_args = argc-1;
// Creating pthread for periodic task ( runs Thread function to run periodically)
  printf("Give task with specifications");
  s1.task_type= 'P';
  s1.period= 300;
  s1.r_min= 400;
  s1.r_max= 500;

 pthread_t tid;
 pthread_attr_t attr;
 pthread_attr_init(&attr);
 pthread_create(tid, &attr, periodic_task, &s1);



  pthread_join(tid, NULL);

}
```

Please give any feedback possible.

Comment: `pthread_create(tid, ....` ==> `pthread_create(&tid, &a....`

Comment: and `warning: passing argument 1 of ‘pthread_create’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  pthread_create(tid, &attr, periodic_task, &s1);`  Warning says it all.

Comment: You already got the answer thread id is pointer you need to send in the address i.e, &tid. A pointer to a pthread_t variable, in which the thread ID of the new thread is stored.

Answer (score 2):

`pthread_t` is the data type used to uniquely identify a thread. This reason why it is passed as a pointer and not as a value to `pthread_create()` is because it is populated and returned by `pthread_create()` to be used by the application in function calls that require a thread identifier. See this [reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/ptcrea.htm).

That is why your call should be as follows:

```
pthread_create(&tid, &attr, periodic_task, &s1);
```